# Host not pingable from container

Tags: networking, routing, ping, docker

From the container an internal system is not reachable:

```
root@c65251d975e4:/# ping -c 1 10.97.179.110
PING 10.97.179.110 (10.97.179.110) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.97.179.110 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Other internet hosts are pingable:

```
root@c65251d975e4:/# ping -c 1 8.8.8.8      
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=14.2 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.273/14.273/14.273/0.000 ms
```

The routing table has nothing special:

```
root@c65251d975e4:/# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

And from the docker host, there is no problem:

```
» ping -c 1 10.97.179.110
PING 10.97.179.110 (10.97.179.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.97.179.110: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=6.87 ms

--- 10.97.179.110 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.872/6.872/6.872/0.000 ms
```

What could the problem be?

### EDIT

If I start the container with host networking, it works:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --network host xenial-networking bash

root@polyphemus:/# ping -c 1 10.97.179.110                                                                │172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.254.0.0     U     0      0        0 tunsnx
PING 10.97.179.110 (10.97.179.110) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                  │172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-1ad6626c6f69
64 bytes from 10.97.179.110: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=8.45 ms                                               │172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.128.0   U     0      0        0 tunsnx
                                                                                                          │172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-eb037ec5c424
--- 10.97.179.110 ping statistics ---                                                                     │172.22.128.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.192.0   U     0      0        0 tunsnx
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms                                               │172.22.192.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 tunsnx
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.457/8.457/8.457/0.000 ms
```

How can I get networking working in the normal networking mode (bridge mode)